# Parallel algorithms in Erlang

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, erlang

I have to write a paper where I describe and write parallel algorithms in Erlang. Could you point some good reads or examples? THANKS

Comment: "Programming Erlang" (Armstrong), "Erlang Programming" (Cesarini, Thompson), [Learn You Some Erlang for Great Good](http://learnyousomeerlang.com).

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic